# Mods vs. Add-ons

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, game-modifications

An extremely small subset of [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) questions aside, the usage of [add-ons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-ons) vs. [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) appears to be strictly arbitrary.

Does someone have a compelling reason to keep both tags, or shall I move [add-ons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-ons) to [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)? (Perhaps with a synonym, even!)

Comment: Did you do this already, or is search borked? I see no questions tagged [Add-on] at the moment. - - - E: nevermind, fixing your question as written...

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, outside of a few misuses by people who mean DLC (and one Dwarf Fortress question), the remainder of questions tagged Add-ons specifically pertain to UI Mods for WoW. Not unsurprisingly, 'add-on' is the preferred term for WoW UI mods for the most part, and is the one most people use when discussing them.

My vote: Fix the guys that mean DLC/Expansions, leave 'add-on' in place for WoW/other games that might use the term to explicitly refer to UI only modifications such as those WoW allows. Those sorts of questions are sufficiently distinct from most questions tagged 'Mod' as to deserve their own tag anyway.

Comment: That said, once this is resolved, if [Add-ons] is kept around, I'd like to see the plural dropped. It's inconsistent with the rest of our tags to have it.

Comment: @Matthew if it should be a synonym of anything, it certainly *shouldn't be* DLC. It should be of Mods or nothing -  look at the current usage of Add-ons, and you'll see it's overwhelmingly questions about WoW UI mods.

Comment: Tags should, on the whole, work like language. Descriptive, not Prescriptive. They should reflect the usage and terminology that people are going to use naturally -  if a particular usage is overwhelmingly dominant, it shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: 6 and 3. Dwarf Therapist is an outlier as it's not DLC but a more typical fan-made mod. But this is splitting hairs, as it's clear we're not going to agree on this with the small size of the dataset available to us.